# Is it good to learn Dart or i must stay with the basic javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, client-side, dart

Is it better to stay with the basic Javascript language or will Dart save me a lot of time? I think Dart looks like very cool software, but will it increase my production? Is Dart code faster than javascript?

Is it a good way to go or is it still unclear whether to choose to learn it?

My goal is to make very good animated websites, with some complex custom transitions. I do well with jQuery, but i want to be more specific and professional than using jQuery plugins and tweak it.

Thank you very much for your help and advice.

Comment: What sort of stuff are you trying?  What kind of project size are you looking at?

Comment: Why you all donwgrading my question? I just want some advices from pros and people who know both sides. Please be kind

Comment: I didn't downgrade your post, but usually questions of the form of "what's better" or anything that could be opinionated tend to get downgraded and have a very good chance of being closed as "not productive".  I recommend you edit your post to sound more objective and sound less like it's asking for an opinion.  Maybe something about some pros and cons and suitability?

Comment: I never understood why asking for an opinion is such a big "no-no!" on stackoverflow. Especially since, whenever someone answers a question about "how do I do ... ?" with "don't do that!" (which is usually that person's opinion), they end up getting a lot of UP votes?!?! Strange...

Comment: You may want to ask this question on programmers.stackexchange.com. @Markus Stack Overflow is great for questions that have verifiable, exact answers. "How do I do X?" is a good format.

Comment: @SethLadd Agreed! I'm just surprised that "Don't do X!" is an answer to that question that always gets a lot of up votes even though it violates exactly this format (it's usually based on someone's opinion and usually leads to subjective discussion). Just an inconsistency that bothers me sometimes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It all comes down to what you are trying to do and what your requirements are.  I recommend you read some of the Dart vs. Javascript pages (to get both sides of the story) and ask yourself where you stand after reading those.

Here are some quick links from a Google of "Dart vs. Javascript".  Please note that these links may not be balanced or even have very good reasons, but I hope they are enough to get you started.  I highly recommend that you look for some more comparisons and do your own research on both sides of the issue:

Here's a pro-Dart page, but one that gives details on why the poster likes Dart:
http://www.grobmeier.de/10-reasons-why-dart-is-cooler-than-javascript-03012012.html#.UL0kXuT7J8E

And here's a more pro-Javascript angle:
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/10/dart_or_why_jav.html

Again, don't take these links as instructions on whether you should or should not use Dart.  Rather, read WHY each link supports one or the other then ask yourself if that reasoning applies to your case.

Comment: (I decided to stop reading after the first paragraph, so take this with a grain of salt) The guy who pro-Javascript page is missing entirely that Dart will not just be a runtime replacement for Javascript that needs to be supported by every device and browser. They are (planning on) offering a Dart-to-Javascript cross-compiler. So, you code in Dart and it compiles to Javascript, which then runs everywhere if needed. Or, if the browser supports it, it can run the Dart code instead. Don't get me wrong: I'm not on either side of this debate as I haven't tried Dart yet, but this seems important.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's an answer like this i wanted to hear. Why people have so much hate?

Comment: @Markus: Thanks for bringing that up.  I just provided the links as a starting point so the OP could get situated.  I definitely did not intend for the links to be the sole sources, so I did not find the two best pro-con links!  I went ahead and edited my post to make sure this was clear.

Comment: @user1161318 No worries! Wasn't meant to criticize your link. I'm sure there's value in that view-point, just wanted to add a small correction to it. Cheers :)

Comment: I'm glad you did; it's important the OP gets a balanced perspective and is not mislead by any answers that left out any info.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MikeBoutin: So basically *"it depends"* is what you wanted to hear?

Comment: @Markus - The only part of the pro-JS post I thought was applicable: `If you like Java and can’t get yourself to like JavaScript, you program Dart.`. It's hard to make an anti-Dart post because Dart can compile to fairly efficient JS.

Comment: That pro-dart article has a couple white lies, specifically about the foreach and arrays.

Answer (score 5):

This talk where Google introduced Dart at the last Google I/O conference earlier this year might answer a bunch of your questions and considerations:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsGgfUreyZw

In short: It doesn't sound like Dart is at the point where it's really that useful yet. So one of the things you need to consider is: When do you need the tool by. If it's now, stay away from Dart (for now).

If you are interested in alternatives to coding in plain JavaScript, you should also check out the Google Web Toolkit. I have a feeling Dart might even be the evolution of GWT.

GWT is very mature, ready for action today, and uses Java for development, which, combined with Eclipse or IntelliJ delivers amazing productivity that I don't think is possible in JavaScript. Especially for complex applications that need to run cross-browser and actually be reasonably bug-free.

Here's a (pretty old, but) good intro to GWT as well, also from Google I/O (but 2008):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvti32k4xyU (replaced the link... this one is better)

Comment: Also on a similar note, look at all the languages that have been built "on top of" Javascript -- that basically use it as a VM for their output.  Lots of stuff out there.